# Determining the best filter order for linear predictive coding

Tags: audio, compression, signal-processing, flac

I am wondering if there is an established method for choosing the best filter order to use when performing linear predictive coding (such as that used in audio file formats like FLAC).

My current approach is:

1. Take a chunk of signal
2. Window the signal with a 0.5 tukey window
3. Get the auto-correlation coefficients
4. Calculate the LPC coefficients using the auto-correlation coefficients
5. Generate the predicted signal using a standard FIR filter with the LPC coefficients
6. Measure the error between the original and predicted signal
7. Goto step 1 and continue repeating with different filter orders
   ...
8. Choose best order based on lowest error

Is it possible to estimate the best filter order by looking at the error created from step 4 of the process? I would like to shortcut to step 8 from step 4 if possible.

Comment: I've long been interested in this as well, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned FLAC, I had a look at how they do it. It looks like in the process of calculating the LPC coefficients, they estimate the errors for all orders up to the max. The overall computation starts [here](http://osxr.org/android/source/external/flac/libFLAC/stream_encoder.c#3300),  they use [FLAC__lpc_compute_lp_coefficients](http://osxr.org/android/source/external/flac/libFLAC/lpc.c#0112) to compute the coeffs and also estimate the error. This is then used in [FLAC__lpc_compute_best_order](http://osxr.org/android/source/external/flac/libFLAC/lpc.c#1359) to decide what coefficient to use (in the nonexhaustive case).

Another implementation to look at is [libflake](http://sourceforge.net/p/flake-enc/code/HEAD/tree/libflake/lpc.c#l125), which is choosing the highest order *n* with *n-1*'s reflection coefficient > .10. This seems related to the approach described [here (PDF)](http://www.rle.mit.edu/soundtosense/conference/pdfs/fulltext/Saturday%20Posters/SB-Vallabha-STS.pdf) which chooses the lowest order *n* when *n+1* and *n+2*'s reflection coefficients are < .15. Both are looking for the point where the reflection coef blows up, but looking at figure 1 in the aforementioned PDF it looks like taking the search from above as Flake does makes more sense. Just another heuristic but might be interesting.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the FLAC implementation, but can I say that I think it's not right? I have run several MATLAB simulations and it produces different results from the FLAC code. Most notably, in their levinson recursion they initialise the lambda error to the auto-correlation coefficient in every loop as opposed to starting at zero, which I don't *think* is correct (it's certainly different to other literature on the subject). Additionally, I suspect that the FLAC codec is *not* picking the best order (again based on MATLAB simulations).

Comment: I agree, it's just a heuristic, but that might be the best you can do without going exhaustive. In the interest of another heuristic, I've edited my answer with some stuff on libflake's approach.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on this. I am going to have a closer look at libflake as well. It seems that a heuristic is perhaps the best I can hope for at this stage. Thanks again :).